# What if my train is delayed causing my ticket to expire?

Tags: trains, germany, berlin, deutsche-bahn

**Example:**

I am at Kähnsdorf Dorf, Seddiner See.
I want to go to Konigs Wusterhausen.

```
Bus (646 -> 643) 17:14 - 17:55 Kähnsdorf Dorf, Seddiner See to Potsdam Bhf.
IC 2431 18:00 - 19:01
```

Total time = 1 hour 47 minutes

On the IC, they accept VBB tickets. So, I want to buy an ABC ticket for 3.40. It is valid for 2 hours. The problem is if my second train is delayed, I may be fined for not having a ticket. Is this possible?

Comment: what is ABC ticket?

Comment: I assume it is referring to a ticket valid in zones AB & C. I know we Berlin uses this notation (https://www.visitberlin.de/en/public-transport-berlin) but I'm not certain if the question is about Berlin and other places probability use a similar system.

Comment: Im sure that every reasonable conductor would understand the problem (and you won't get fined), if you can show that your connection would have fallen into the two hour period if the train would have been on time. However I couldn't find anything official (e.g. in the conditions of carriage) to back this up, hence it's not an answer. Besides that: Did you ask the VBB directly, because they should know best how they handle such cases.

Comment: This should be no different than any other case of a delay within VBB.

Comment: @simbabque [VBB tickets are valid on that IC](http://www.vbb.de/de/article/startseite/besonderheiten-bahn/fernverkehrszuege-zum-vbb-tarif/898.html).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the bus stop "Kähnsdorf Dorf" is not part of the Berlin-C-area (it is part of the Potsdam C area though, which is something different). So an ABC ticket should not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you are always allowed to take the currently fastest connection to your destination. This follows from section B 5.3.1 of the [VBB fare regulation](http://images.vbb.de/assets/downloads/file/1161285.pdf):

> Diese Einzelfahrausweise (außer Kurzstrecke) berechtigen zu einer Fahrt mit beliebigem Umsteigen in Richtung auf das Fahrtziel über den reiseüblichen oder durch die Fahrplanlage bedingten Weg.
>
> *(Those [e.g. Berlin fare area] single tickets (except for short journey tickets) entitle the holder to a journey with any change in direction to the destination via the usual route or the route determined by the current timetable situation.)*

Only if you wish to interrupt your journey, the time limits become applicable:

> Fahrtunterbrechungen sind innerhalb der nachfolgend aufgeführten Fahrzeitbegrenzung beliebig oft gestattet [...] im Tarifbereich Berlin 120 Minuten.
>
> *(Travel interruptions are permitted as often as desired within the travel time limit listed below [...] in the Berlin fare area 120 minutes.)*

So, in short: if you get delayed on your journey for reasons other than your own fault, you can always travel to your destination.

However, what you plan on doing is not possible for another reason: The stop "Kähnsdorf Dorf, Seddiner See" is located in zone "6049 Kähnsdorf, Dorf", which is not part of the "Berlin C area" as evidenced by the [VBB zone list](http://images.vbb.de/assets/downloads/file/1161287.pdf). Note that there is an unrelated concept of a "Potsdam C area" which that stop is in but that's something else. So a VBB Berlin ABC ticket is not valid for a journey starting in Kähnsdorf. For the journey from your question you would need a "VBB R2 (Regionaltarif bis 25 km)" ticket for 4.30 € which allows you to travel to your destination with the fastest currently possible connection.

Comment: What if your first train is delayed, causing your ticket to expire preventing you from using your next connection?

Comment: @trinalbadger587 As I said, those tickets don't expire as long as you always take the next connection that is possible in reality. The time limits are only in case you want to interrupt your journey for longer than the next possible connection.

Comment: It's worth noting that the VBB R2 ticket that is required for this journey doesn't even have a time limit defined. You always need to take the next actual connection that brings you closer to the destination.